# SQL Server : remove character from string variable with CONTAINTABLE and JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a string variable in my SQL Server stored procedure.

The string variable has a special character like '-' which I like to remove.

Here is my current sql statement

```
declare @MyString varchar4(100) = '00-999'
select [ProductId],[RANK] AS RANK0
from MyTable mt
join CONTAINSTABLE (MyTable, *, @MyString ) AS cnt
on cnt.[KEY] = mt.ProductId
```

This query works but I want search via FullTextSearch for both 00-999 and 00999. 
Basically do a fulltextsearch for both string value with and without the hyphen and combine the results as though I was doing a union.

I tried this query but I am getting syntax error from sql server studio

```
select [ProductId],[RANK] AS RANK0
from MyTable mt
join CONTAINSTABLE (MyTable, *, @MyString ) AS cnt
  on cnt.[KEY] = mt.ProductId
join CONTAINSTABLE (MyTable, *, replace(@MyString, '-', '') ) AS cnt
  on cnt.[KEY] = mt.ProductId
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks. Newbie

Comment: What is the error? I see you use the alias `cnt` twice.

Answer (score 2):

Added

```
set @MyString = (select replace(@KeyWord, '-', ''))
```

used @MyString in the CONTAINSTABLE function. It worked